# Merging sentences after merging spans

Tags: python, spacy

Suppose I have a sentence

'Using Data.Frames allows you to handle data efficiently'

Using spacy this example will be split into two sentences:

```
>> example = 'Using Data.Frames allows you to handle data efficiently'
>> doc = nlp(example)
>> list(doc.sents)
[Using Data., Frames allows you to handle data efficiently]
```

Following the [recommendation from this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594759/spacy-adding-special-case-tokenization-rules-by-regular-expression-or-pattern) I can partially solve this problem through span merging, like so

```
>> doc[1:4].merge()
>> doc[1]
Data.Frame
```

However this will not merge the previously split sentences

```
>>> list(doc.sents)
[Using Data.Frames, allows you to handle data efficiently]
```

What would be the best way to reprocess sentence tokenization after a set of merging operations have been applied? This is important for me because I need to navigate the parsing tree afterwards.

P.S. In my real application I need to use regular expressions to identify this special case abbreviations (roughly `[A-Za-z0-9-:]+.[A-Z][a-z0-9A-Z]+`) ., hence why I cannot use spacy's add_special_case. Maybe I could use a custom tokenizer but I'm not sure how to go about it.

---

- **Python version:** 2.7.12
- **Platform:** Linux-4.4.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-18-sarah
- **spaCy version:** 2.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem through a custom tokenizer based approach, which means the sentence is never broken in the first place avoiding the need to merge it later.

Based on the information [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-tokenization) in the documentation, when you create a custom tokenizer the token_match argument can be used to match patterns that should never be broken. Like this, you can set:

```
def custom_en_tokenizer(nlp):
    pattern_re = re.compile('<some regex martching a pattern that is broken>')
    return spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer(nlp.vocab,
                                     English.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions,
                                     English.Defaults.prefixes,
                                     English.Defaults.suffixes,
                                     English.Defaults.infixes,
                                     token_match=pattern_re.match)

nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp.tokenizer = custom_en_tokenizer(nlp)
```