# Python snippet to manage regex replacement index map?

Tags: python, regex, text

For text processing task i need to apply multiple regex substitutions (i.e. re.sub). There are multiple regex patterns with custom replacement parameters. **The result needs to be original text, text with replacements and a map of tuples identifying start,end indices of replaced strings in source text and indices in result text.**

e.g. 
following is a sample code having input text and an array of 3 modifier tuples.

```
text = '''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. On Apr. 6th, 2009 Ut enim culpa minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 5 ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. On June 23rd, 3004 excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 6 mollit anim id est laborum.
'''

modifiers = [
    (
        r'([\w]+\.?)\s+(\d{1,2})\w{2},\s+(\d{4})', 
        { 1:lambda x:month(x), 2:lambda x:num2text(x), 3:lambda x:num2text(x) }
    ),
    (
        r' (\d) ', 
        { 1:lambda x:num2text(x) }
    ),
    (
        r'(culpa)', 
        { 1: 'culpae' }
    )
]
```

sample output index map:

```
[((7, 11), (7, 30)), ((12, 14), (31, 35)), ((20, 22), (41, 51)), ((23, 28), (52, 57)),...]
```

Already wrote a complicated function, that tries to handle all the corner cases of the index offsetting happening during replacements, but it's already taking too much time.

Maybe there is already a solution for this task?

Here is [a **demo** of current state](https://repl.it/repls/ExperiencedYummyChief). 
Word transformation expansion (normalization) functions were intentionally made simplistic with fixed value dict mapping.

The ultimate goal is to make a text dataset generator. Dataset needs to have two text parts - one with numbers abbreviations and other expandable strings and the other with fully expanded into full textual representation (e.g. 3->three, apr. -> april, etc.) And also offset mapping to link parts of non-expanded text with corresponding parts in expanded text.

One of the corner cases that my implementation already deals with is a  case when there are at least two modifiers A and B and they have to deal with text like 'text text a text b text a text b' as first modifier churns out output span of the second 'a' replacement becomes incorrect as B modifier comes in and alters output text before second 'a'.

Also partially dealt with case where subsequent modifier replaces output replacement from first modifier and figures out the initial source span location.

### UPDATE

[Writing a python package](https://github.com/aleksas/re-map/) called [re-map](https://pypi.org/project/re-map/).
One might also consider [spacy](https://spacy.io/api/span#merge) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623232/1433554).

Comment: And what have tried so far ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus just extending re.sub functionality by providing custom repl function. 60 lines of code, but too obfuscated and complex to continue. Would need to rewrite anew to move further.But my guess is that such task should be somewhat popular...

Comment: ...so looking for simpler solutions not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Added link to the code to the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wrote](https://github.com/aleksas/re-map/) a [re-map](https://pypi.org/project/re-map/) python library to solve the problem described.

Here is [a **demo**](https://repl.it/repls/ExperiencedYummyChief).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example that handles your text modifiers using `re`, `datetime` and a third party package called `inflect`.

The code will return the modified text with the position of the modified words.

**PS:** You need to explain more what you're trying to do. Otherwise you can use this code and modify it to fulfill your needs.

To install `inflect`: `pip install inflect`

**Sample code:**

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
import inflect

ENGINE = inflect.engine()


def num2words(num):
    """Number to Words using inflect package"""
    return ENGINE.number_to_words(num)


def pretty_format_date(pattern, date_found, text):
    """Pretty format dates"""
    _month, _day, _year = date_found.groups()
    month = datetime.strptime('{day}/{month}/{year}'.format(
        day=_day, month=_month.strip('.'), year=_year
    ), '%d/%b/%Y').strftime('%B')
    day, year = num2words(_day), num2words(_year)
    date = '{month} {day}, {year} '.format(month=month, day=day, year=year)
    begin, end = date_found.span()
    _text = re.sub(pattern, date, text[begin:end])
    text = text[:begin] + _text + text[end:]
    return text, begin, end


def format_date(pattern, text):
    """Format given string into date"""
    spans = []
    # For loop prevents us from going into an infinite loop
    # If there is malformed texts or bad regex
    for _ in re.findall(pattern, text):
        date_found = re.search(pattern, text)
        if not date_found:
            break
        try:
            text, begin, end = pretty_format_date(pattern, date_found, text)
            spans.append([begin, end])
        except Exception:
            # Pass without any modification if there is any errors with date formats
            pass

    return text, spans


def number_to_words(pattern, text):
    """Numer to Words with spans"""
    spans = []
    # For loop prevents us from going into an infinite loop
    # If there is malformed texts or bad regex
    for _ in re.findall(pattern, text):
        number_found = re.search(pattern, text)
        if not number_found:
            break
        _number = number_found.groups()
        number = num2words(_number)
        begin, end = number_found.span()
        spans.append([begin, end])
        _text = re.sub(pattern, number, text[begin:end])
        text = text[:begin] + ' {} '.format(_text) + text[end:]
    return text, spans



def custom_func(pattern, text, output):
    """Custom function"""
    spans = []
    for _ in re.findall(pattern, text):
        _found = re.search(pattern, text)
        begin, end = _found.span()
        spans.append([begin, end])
        _text = re.sub(pattern, output, text[begin:end])
        text = text[:begin] + ' {} '.format(_text) + text[end:]
    return text, spans


text = '''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. On Apr. 6th, 2009 Ut enim culpa minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 5 ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. On June 23rd, 3004 excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 6 mollit anim id est laborum.
'''

modifiers = [
    (
        r'([\w]+\.?)\s+(\d{1,2})\w{2},\s+(\d{4})',
        format_date
    ),
    (
        r' (\d) ',
        number_to_words
    ),
    (
        r'( \bculpa\b)',  # Better using this pattern to catch the exact word
        'culpae'
    )
]

for regex, func in modifiers:
    if not isinstance(func, str):
        print('\n{} {} {}'.format('#' * 20, func.__name__, '#' * 20))
        _text, spans = func(regex, text)
    else:
        print('\n{} {} {}'.format('#' * 20, func, '#' * 20))
        _text, spans = custom_func(regex, text, func)
    print(_text, spans)
```

Output:

```
#################### format_date ####################

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. On April six, two thousand and nine  Ut enim culpa minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 5 ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolorin reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. On June 23rd, 3004 excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 6 mollit animid est laborum.
 [[128, 142]]

#################### number_to_words ####################

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. On Apr. 6th, 2009 Ut enim culpa minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex five ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. On June 23rd, 3004 excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt six mollit anim id est laborum.
 [[231, 234], [463, 466]]

#################### culpae ####################

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. On Apr. 6th, 2009 Ut enim culpae  minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 5 ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolorin reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. On June 23rd, 3004 excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpae  qui officia deserunt 6 mollit anim id est laborum.
 [[150, 156], [435, 441]]
```

**Demo on [Replit](https://repl.it/repls/InternationalUpbeatGenres)**

Comment: The ultimate goal is to make a text dataset generator. Dataset needs to have two text parts - one with numbers aabreviations and other expandable strings and the other with fully expanded into full textual representation (e.g. 3->three, apr. -> april, etc.) And also offset mapping to link parts of non-expanded text with corresponding parts in expanded text.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your code doesn't deal with cases when there are say two modifiers A and B and they have to deal with text like 'text text a text b text a text b' as first modifier churns out spans the value of second span becomes flawed as B modifier comes in and  alters text. The input text indices should be fine but the output text indices are altered with each next modifier because of occurrence mix.

Comment: I have intentionally left out the word transformation expansion (normalization) functions and replaced with simplistic stub functions replacing several fixed values from dict. as this is not the issue

Comment: Updated description to include additional goal/problem explanations.

Comment: You can see in the code I've shared the last instructions to print out text showing input spans and output spans in within the text, you can try it with your spans.

Comment: Updated description added links to new PyPi package. Still work in progress.

Comment: Actually [somthing similar is done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623232/1433554) using [spacy](https://spacy.io/api/span#merge)